# Eclipse 2018-12 with JDK1.8 UI freezes

Tags: java, eclipse, git, ide

I am running Eclipse `2018-12` on a Windows 7 (VM) along with a JDK 1.8.0_121, as a runtime for the IDE and as JDK to build my bundles.

I am already through a couple of re-installations. Yesterday it happened again: **The IDE freezes completely**, **not returning to be responsive even after waiting for several minutes**.

Sometimes the wait cursor disappears and it seems to be responsive, but the first click anyway let the IDE return to its freeze mode.

**What I did** right before was a massive update of the underlying workspace through a `git pull`. Probably thousands of new deleted and changed files.

**I've tried** to start the IDE with `"-clean"` option.
I've created a new workspace, was able to do a couple of clicks here and there, UI freeze again.

I had the same thing with Eclipse `2019-03` and wasn't able to solve it, so I thought `2018-12` was a little more stable concerning this issue.

Is there a known issue with Eclipse-with-GIT? 
Any ideas about how to get the IDE working again?
Is that probably `2018-12/2019-03` specific?

Comment: The current version is Eclipse 2019-06 which uses by default _Apache MINA sshd_ instead of _JSch_ as SSH client. If you can reproduce the issue with Eclipse 2019-06, try to switch the SSH client (_Window > Preferences: Team > Git_).

Comment: Thank you very much, howlger. After reinstalling Eclipse and setting up a new workspace, I can work since 2 days. Installed 2019-06 now and I am ready to set a workspace for it.